# protobuf-net Constructor overriding deserialized value

Tags: .net, vb.net, protobuf-net

I am serializing an object and when loading back I want to set a specific value if a field is missing. For example, if a field is added on version 2, when loading a file generated by version 1, I want to set a value.

Example:

```
<ProtoContract()>
Public Class Settings

    '  ... other members

    <ProtoMember(33)>
    Public AutoZoom As Boolean 


    'Load from a file
    Friend Shared Function Load(filePath as string) As Settings

        Dim result As Settings

        Try
            If IO.File.Exists(filePath) Then
                Using s As New IO.FileStream(filePath, IO.FileMode.Open)
                    result = Serializer.Deserialize(Of Settings)(s)
                End Using
            Else
                result = CreateNew()
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            result = CreateNew()
        End Try

        Return result

    End Function

    Public Shared Function CreateNew() As Settings

        Dim n = New Settings()
        Return n

    End Function        

    Private Sub New()

        AutoZoom = TRUE

    end sub         

End Class
```

I tried to use the constructor thinking that it would run before the field is de-serialized. But it happens that when loading an object from a serialized file, some fields will be loaded with the value inside the file, but some other fields will remain with the value set by the constructor, and the value inside the file will be ignored.
Why is that happening?

PO

Comment: Are the confused values zeros by any chance? Meaning: the constructor sets them non-zero, you serialized them as zero, and they deserialized as non-zero? If so: a missing [DefaultValue(...)]. Alternatively, disable implicit zero defaults (RuntimeTypeModel.UseImplicitZeroDefaults). For anything else, I'll need to see some kind of code.

Comment: The confused values are boolean actually. The field in the constructor is set to TRUE. When I de-serialize knowing that it was saved as FALSE, the resulting de-serialized object has the field set to TRUE.

Comment: for this purpose, false === zero.

Comment: Sorry, I did missed that detail... I swear I read 100 times this default Zeros issue and I always read as the problem being restoring FALSE back again. Thanks!

Comment: I suspect a `[DefaultValue(true)]` (in VB syntax) will sort you out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default (and in line with "proto3", but not "proto2"), protobuf-net assumes zeros (and false, etc) as default values (when a member is not nullable and when no other conditional serialization APIs are detected, such as the inbuilt `public bool ShouldSerialize*()` pattern). It sounds like you have non-zero defaults via the constructor, in which case all you need to do is tell protobuf-net about the actual default values via the attribute `[DefaultValue(...)]` (in `System.ComponentModel`). This will also make other common .NET tools happier, such as `PropertyGrid`, `PropertyDescriptor`, etc).

Alternatively, disable the implicit zero defaults feature (see comments on the post). Then only **explicit** `[DefaultValue]` attributes will be observed.